# Declaring a String as final in "onSubmit()" results in slf4j error

Tags: java, wicket

I am currently working on an Apache Wicket project involving a TextField.

Inside the overriden onSubmit(), I have declared a String as final:

```
String final usernameValue = username.getModelObject();
```

However, as soon as I declare that String, I get:

"The type org.slf4j.Logger cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files", this despite the fact I am not logging anything whatsoever.

If I declare a String anywhere else as final, then all is OK. I have cleaned my project with no effect, (automatic builds are on), and do not know how to resolve this issue.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The unique line of code you posted wouldn't even compile.

Comment: I'm well aware of that, thank you. I chose to include that line because it was the only line causing an error. Everything else is OK.

Comment: I think @JBNizet meant that "String final" is invalid. It should be "final String" instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this by importing two specific .jar files from the slf4j binary:

• slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar

• slf4j-simple-1.7.12.jar, then adding them to the build path

**To do so**

Shift-click on them, to select them both at once, then right-click on them. Scroll down to "Build Path", then click "Add to Build Path".

After, I then temporarily disabled "Build Automatically", then cleaned and built the project manually. I then re-enabled "Build Automatically".

These instructions are for Eclipse.

Comment: You need only slf4j-api in the classpath. The impl is needed only if you want to log something. If you use Maven/Gradle/SBT/... then this is managed automatically for you.